# How to cancel the carriage return and line feed in a node in XQuery？

Tags: xml, xquery

Like the title

I wanna cancel the carriage return and line feed

```
<test>
  ...
  <text>
  ABC
  </text>
  ...
</test>
```

Expected

```
<text>ABC</text>
```

I have tried that

```
let $data := 
<test>
  <text>
  ABC
  </text>
</test>
let $test := $data/text
return replace($test,"&#xA;","")
```

but it gives the result as

```
<text>
ABC</text>
```

Comment: That example still doesn't make any sense to me, you bind an element named `test` to the `data` variable, then select `$data/test`, that would give the empty sequence. And replace on the empty sequence will certainly not output anything like a `text` element with some content.

Comment: It would also help if you tell us which XQuery processor/implementation you use.

Comment: I use BaseX implementation

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your regular expression could remove a trailing line break but not a leading one; I would think you just want `normalize-space()` e.g.

```
/*!element { node-name() } {
  text ! element { node-name()} { replace(., '&#xA;', '') }
}
```

online at [this example](https://xpath.playground.fontoxml.com/?state=H4sIAPOWXmMAA22OvQ7CMAyEX8X1BKg%2FYq0QEvAE7F1C8VApcVESUCHKu2MHwcRk%2B3TfnRO6%2BUrYb2t8GD%2BZi6WAPaaMNS7OyrqLFOJ%2BYIC2bXWIsHyEw%2FFUhO6nFIvegmjC%2BU7%2BKSHdpiJLjjhCApbGho2j1RoyJOU0ACr46xGLnN4ZO72oCTczFnBg%2FXGcWdlvD%2BY3lEQ0vdEAAAA%3D), although your regular expression used in [this example](https://xpath.playground.fontoxml.com/?state=H4sIAOiXXmMAA22OQQrCQAxFr5JGsFXqFLdVhOoJ3Hcz1iyEmVTaKiPD3N2koiuzSfL5eT8RfX8lrLclPu1wsxdHI9YYE5YYvJNxP9E4HVoGMMZoEyF8hOZ4moXqp8wW3eVECecHDS%2BBVOuMHHniCSKwJG7YeipWkCDqnZZCIIO%2FPrHBQHdnOypMCflyEZpdLkMuiJZb1n%2B7npXxzcT0BspC%2BBjdAAAA) e.g.

```
/*!element { node-name() } {
      text ! element { node-name()} { replace(., '&#xA;', '') }
}
```

works as well to remove the line breaks.